# Fullcalendar Event Add/Edit and Resize.and get sucesscallback without page reload/refresh

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-5

When i add new event or update event or change event or drag new time or new user then every time page refreshes. but how to solve this issue for without reloading page and display updated event time or remove event. i'm using calendar version 5 for fullcalendar.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      now: '<?php echo $CurrentDate; ?>',
      editable: true,
      aspectRatio: 1.8,
      scrollTime: '00:00',
      timeFormat: 'H(:mm)',
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'today prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'resourceTimelineDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth'
      },
      resources: <?php eventGroups(); ?>,
      events: function(info, successCallback, failureCallback) {
        successCallback(<?php eventGroupsDetails($fromDate,$toDate); ?>)
      },
      dateClick: function(info) {
        $('#addScheduleEntry').modal('show');
        $(document).on('click', '.modal_default_ok', function() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "calendar_event_create.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: $("#frmEvent").serialize(),
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(response){
                    if(response.result == 'success'){
                        // how to get updated event and display in calender without page refresh
                    }
                }
            });    
        });
      },
      
      eventClick: function(info, jsEvent, view) { 
        $.ajax({
            url: "calendar_event_update.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#frmEventUpdate").serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response){
                // how to get updated event and display in calender without page refresh
            }
        });
      },
      editable: true,
      eventDrop: function(info, delta, revertFunc, ui) {
            $.ajax({
              url: "save_drop_event_detail.php",
              type: "POST",
              data: {EventId:EventId},
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function(response){
                // how to get updated event and display in calender without page refresh
              } 
            });
      },
      eventResize: function(info) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "save_resize_event_detail.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {EventId:EventId},
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(response){
            // how to get updated event and display in calender without page refresh
          } 
        });
      }
    });
    calendar.render();
  });
</script>
<div class="row"> 
    <div id="msg"></div>
    <div class="col-md-12"> 
        <div id='calendar'></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: None of the code you've shown would cause the page to refresh by itself. Maybe something elsewhere in your code is the cause of that.

Comment: As for your question "how to get updated event and display in calender without page refresh"...you could call `calendar.refetchEvents()` which tells fullCalendar to refresh the event data from the server. This would work **if** you had an AJAX data source for your events, instead of a static one. You asked about this in your previous question, and I gave you all the information about how to implement it, but you don't seem to have done anything about it - your event data is still hard-coded into your script via a PHP function.

Comment: Can you please provide  how to store sample json data for events.

Comment: huh? Store the event data in your database, and use PHP to get the data from the database and encode it as JSON. Then tell fullCalendar the URL it can use to call that PHP script whenever it needs to fetch events. There are loads of examples online of people doing this task (or very similar json-encoding tasks) in PHP, you can find examples easily. You don't seem to have put any effort into any basic research yet.

Comment: Hi thank you for your support i will successfully complete this issue has been resolve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
      now: '<?php echo $CurrentDate; ?>',
      editable: true,
      aspectRatio: 1.8,
      headerToolbar: {
        left: 'today prev,next',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'resourceTimelineDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth'
      },
      views: {
        timeGridWeek: {
          type: 'timeGrid',
          duration: { weeks: <?php if($searchWeek=="") { echo 1; } else{echo $searchWeek;} ?> }
        }
      },
      resources: <?php eventGroups(); ?>,
      events: function(fetchInfo, successCallback, failureCallback) {
        var fromDate = "<?php echo $fromDate; ?>";
        var toDate = "<?php echo $toDate; ?>";
        $.ajax({
          url: "ajaxRefresh.php",
          type: "POST",
          dataType: "json",
          success: function(response){
            var events = [];
            $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                events.push({
                  id: response[i].id,
                  start: response[i].start,
                  end: response[i].end,
                  title: response[i].title,
                });
            });
            successCallback(events);
          }
        });
      },
      dateClick: function(info) {
        $('#addScheduleEntry').modal('show');
        $.ajax({
            url: "calendar_event_create.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#frmEvent").serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            async : false,
            success: function(response){
              if(response.result == 'success'){
                calendar.refetchEvents();
              }
            }
        });
      },
      eventClick: function(info, jsEvent, view) { 
        var text = JSON.stringify(info, function (key, value) {
        var eventId = info.event._def.publicId;
          $("#eventDetail").modal("show");  

          $(document).on('click', '.removeEvent', function() {
            var eventId = $("#event_id").val();
            var yes = confirm("Are you sure ?");
            if(yes == true){
              $("#process_loader").fadeIn();  
              $.ajax({
                url: "calendar_event_remove.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {eventId:eventId},
                dataType: 'json',
                async : false,
                success: function(response){
                  if(response.msg == "true"){
                    calendar.refetchEvents();
                  }
                }
              });
            }
          });
      },
      editable: true,
      eventDrop: function(info, delta, revertFunc, ui) {
        $.ajax({
          url: "save_drop_event_detail.php",
          type: "POST",
          data: {EventId:EventId,oldUserId:oldUserId,newUserId:newUserId,newEventStartTime:newEventStartTime,newEventEndTime:newEventEndTime},
          dataType: 'json',
          async : false,
          success: function(response){
            if(response.msg == 'success'){
              calendar.refetchEvents();
            }
          } 
        });
      },
      eventConstraint: {
        slotMinTime: '10:00' ,
        slotMaxTime: '11:00'
      }

    });
    calendar.render();
  });
</script>
```

We used this function "**calendar.refetchEvents();**" and used an AJAX data source for your events, instead of a static one.

Comment: All of this: `  var events = [];
            $.each(response, function (i, item) {
                events.push({
                  id: response[i].id,
                  start: response[i].start,
                  end: response[i].end,
                  title: response[i].title,
                });
            });` is not necessary. You're just creating an identical array to the one you've already got, which is pointless. Instead you can just write `successCallback(response)` directly.

Comment: Ok we have remove and update successCallback(response) and is working fine thank you.